# Condition number, well conditioned or ill condition

Tags: numerical-methods, condition-number

> Determine the condition number for taking the square root of a number $x$. Is this problem well-conditioned or ill-conditioned

I know that conditioning measures how sensitive a problem is to a small change in the initial data. The condition number $k$ of a problem $P : R^m \rightarrow R^n$ is the smallest number such

$$\frac{\left| \hat{x_i}-x_i\right|}{\left|x_i\right|} \leq \epsilon $$for all $1 \leq i \leq m$ then

$$\frac{||P(\hat x)-P(x)||}{||P(x)||} \le k \epsilon + 0(\epsilon)$$ where little $0$ is Landau.

I am not quite sure how to use this for my example.

If we let $\hat {x} = \sqrt x (1+\epsilon)$ then

$$\frac{||P(\hat x)-P(x)||}{||P(x)||} = \frac{||\sqrt x (1+\epsilon)-\sqrt x||}{||\sqrt x||}= \frac{||\sqrt x + \sqrt x\epsilon - \sqrt x||}{\sqrt x} = \sqrt x \frac{||\epsilon||}{\sqrt x} = || \epsilon || $$

I found an answer with no detail saying that $k = \frac{1}{2}$ and that it was well-conditioned but I am not sure how my above calculation would how that.

Looking for some help with this, thanks!

Comment: **Hint:** Consider $k$ as a ratio of the (relative) error in the function value $\sqrt{x}$ to the (relative) error in the argument $x$ and simplify, i.e. $$ k \approx \frac{\frac{\sqrt{\hat x} - \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}}{ \frac{\hat x - x}{x}} $$

Comment: @Hardmath wouldn't that simplify to $$\frac{x \sqrt {\hat x} - x \sqrt x}{\hat x \sqrt x - x\sqrt x}$$? how would that simplify to 1/2, could you show me this simplification?

Comment: okay pulling that gives $$\frac{x}{\sqrt x} \frac{\sqrt {\hat x}-\sqrt x}{\hat x - x}$$ then what?

Comment: @hardmath what would come next

Comment: Rationalize the numerator.

Comment: $$\frac{x}{\sqrt x} \frac{\sqrt {\hat x}-\sqrt x}{\hat x - x} \frac{\sqrt {\hat x} + \sqrt x}{\sqrt {\hat x}+\sqrt x}\\ = \frac { x}{\sqrt x} \frac{\hat x + \sqrt {\hat x}\sqrt x - \sqrt {\hat x}\sqrt x - x}{\hat x \sqrt {\hat x} + \hat x \sqrt x - x \sqrt {\hat x} - x \sqrt x}\\ = \frac{x}{\sqrt x} \frac{\hat x + \sqrt {\hat x }\sqrt x -\sqrt {\hat x}\sqrt x - x}{\hat x \sqrt {\hat x} + \hat x \sqrt x - x \sqrt {\hat x - x\sqrt x}}$$

Comment: @hardmath this is what I got, how does that simplify or did I make a mistake? really would like to finish this question

Comment: @hardmath okay so now we have $$\frac{x}{\sqrt x} \frac{\hat x - x}{\hat x \sqrt {\hat x} +\hat x \sqrt x - x\sqrt {\hat x}-x\sqrt x}$$ then what?

Comment: Remember that you expanded the product in the denominator.   Go back to its factored form, and you will see how to proceed.

Comment: @hardmath but what can I factor out of the denominator?

Comment: I must of made a mistake somewhere

Comment: Your denominator is the product of the two things you multiplied together above, $(\hat x - x)$ and $(\sqrt{\hat x} + \sqrt x)$.  Just put them back in that factored form.

Comment: @hardmath okay now I believe we have $$\frac{x}{\sqrt x} \frac{\hat x - x}{(\hat x - x)(\sqrt {\hat x} + \sqrt x)} = \frac{x}{\sqrt x (\sqrt {\hat x+x)}} $$

Comment: then what?......

Comment: You have some typos in the right hand side, but fix them and you'll have an expression that is approximately $1/2$.

Comment: @hardmath okay it should be $$\frac{x}{\sqrt x (\sqrt {\hat x}+x)}$$

Comment: how is that approximately $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: You should slow down.  It is: $$ \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{\hat x} + \sqrt{x})} $$

Comment: @hardmath yes that's what I have I just had a typo. Then how is that approximately 1/2?

Comment: if it is 1/2 I know its a small enough number and therefore it would be well conditioned

Comment: What is $\sqrt x$ times $\sqrt x$?

Comment: it is just $x$.

Comment: @hardmath so then we would just have $$\frac{x}{\sqrt x \sqrt {\hat x } + x}$$

Comment: ...which is close to $1/2$ because $\hat x$ is close to $x$.

Comment: @hardmath okay so I just say that that is close to 1/2 which is the condition number, making it well conditioned

Comment: I think you should sleep on it and it will seem clearer to you in the morning.  In general the calculation of the condition number is often simplified by using derivatives and the Mean Value Thm.  Here the derivative of the square root function is what contributes the factor $1/2$.

Comment: @hardmath okay so since $\hat x$ is close to $x$ we have $\frac{x}{\sqrt x \sqrt {\hat x}+x} = \frac{x}{x+x} = \frac{x}{2x} \approx. \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @hardmath thanks for your help! last question, that makes the condition number 1/2 which is small enough that we can say it is well conditioned?

Comment: Yes, $1/2$ is the condition number, and it isn't very big.

Comment: okay thanks for everything!